# Trying to install Ubuntu Touch, what is sources.list?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am following instructions for installing Ubuntu Touch onto my phone, and I am at a loss for the instruction asking me to append my sources.list.  Can someone please clue me in?  Below is the context

> The PPA has the tools and dependencies to support Precise, Quantal,
>   and Raring. Add the Ubuntu Touch PPA by adding the following custom
>   source list entry to your /etc/apt/sources.list file.
>
> On your computer, press Ctrl+Alt+T to start a terminal.
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
> ```
>
> or if add-apt-repository is not available, append the following to
>   your sources.list:
>
> ```
> deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu [dist-codename] main
> deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu [dist-codename] main
> ```
>
> *Note: replace [dist-codename] with precise, quantal, raring or saucy.
>
> Then do the following:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
```

Thus, is not necessary to edit manually `sources.list` which is located in `/etc/apt` directory.

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SourcesList:

> The sources.list file is a key factor in adding or upgrading
>   applications to your Ubuntu installation. This is also used by your
>   system for system updates. The file is basically the roadmap for your
>   system to know where it may download programs for installation or
>   upgrade.

Also, in the future when you hear about a file and you don't know exactly where is located, you can use the the following command ion terminal to find it:

```
locate file_name
```

Comment: I don't think this works. On a Volla X23, this command runs into the same problem described in the question: `OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: `'/etc/apt/sources.list.save'`

Answer (score 0):

It's a file that lists the 'sources' from which packages can be obtained. You can read more here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine